# Wrapper around ParSeq, splitter is protected

Tags: scala, oop, parseq

I am trying to make a wrapper class around ParSeq, in order to extend with some of my own functionality. This is what I have so far

```
class MyParSeq[A](s: ParSeq[A]) extends ParSeq[A] {
  override def apply(i: Int):  A = s(i)
  override def length: Int = s.length
  override def seq: Seq[A] = s.seq
  override protected def splitter: SeqSplitter[A] = ???
}
```

I understand what the splitter does and I would like the same parallel semantics as ParSeq, only problem; the splitter is marked `protected`. How do I wrap around ParSeq without redefining the SeqSplitter?

Comment: If you want to just extend it and not completely reimplement it, you should probably use extension methods.

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik sure that's possible, but I also want to find if its possible to wrap around the ParSeq splitter in this way first. The fact that its protected is kind of annoying, I almost wish Scala had `friend` classes like C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `SeqSplitter` is protected, then you shouldn't really try to redefine it.

The more canonical way to extend classes with additional methods in Scala is by using a pattern called *extension methods* (also called [implicit classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) in Scala).

```
implicit class ParSeqOps[A](parSeq: ParSeq[A]) {//name of parameter doesn't matter, only type
    def second: A  = parSeq(1) //you can define multiple methods here
    def isLengthEven: Boolean = parSeq.length % 2 == 0
}
```

Whenever *implicit* class **ParSeqOps** is in scope, you'd be able to use all methods you defined like they were members of **ParSeq**:

```
ParSeq(1,2,3,4).second // 2
ParSeq(1,2,3,4).isLengthEven //true
```

Comment: Yep alright I am sold on why this is the right approach. Thanks!